# GTA V online won't save

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

While playing GTA Online, I received a message that read "Unable to connect to rockstar games services". I forced the game to close, which showed a "Save successful" message, but I still lost all my progress. I just started and I simply don't have the time to get enough cash for a house and clothes in order to even try the “change outfit” method. I even logged off into story mode, saved story mode and closed the game and it still didn’t work.

I'm playing on a laptop not a PC and I have BitDefender 2019. I say this as I read that it may be my anti virus that’s blocking the process.

How can I fix this issue and save my game properly?

Comment: Buy a car or do something else that requires spending money.

Answer (score -2):

Disable your Antivirus. I had the same problem using Bitdefender.